# Unable to connect to my Tfs server from c# code

Tags: c#, tfs, credentials, azure-devops

We're trying to authenticate to our hosted [TFS service account](http://tfspreview.com/) in c# using TeamFoundationServer .net control, here is my code :

```
NetworkCredential tfsCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
TeamFoundationServer tfsServer = new TeamFoundationServer(tfsAddress, tfsCredential);

tfsServer.Authenticate();
```

Note that this is *not* an on-premises TFS server, it is the hosted TFS service at [tfspreview.com](http://tfspreview.com/) and we try to sign-in with windows live account and with alternate authentication credentials but every time we try to authenticate, internet explorer open in a new windows and ask for credentials.

If we use the IE prompt to connect it works but we want to store the credentials and connect to the server without asking for the credentials every time,

Answer (score 1):

You can either configure basic authentication under your profile or you can use a service credential. It all depends on what sort of permission you need. The basic auth operates under a user account which tends to be bad practice while the service account had elevated permissions.

**Configure basic authentication for TF Service**

For basic user authentication you should connect to TF Service and open your profile as indicated. There is a "Credentials" tab on your profile which will let you configure those credentials. This is good for per/user access through the API but is not good if you want to run things through a server or service.

[image: Configure basic authentication for TF Service]

**Retrieve TFS Service Credentials**

I created an application called the [TFS Service Credential Viewer](http://nakedalm.com/tfs-service-credential-viewer/) that allows you to retrieve the service credentials for your TF Service instance. This is the same thing that the Build & Test servers do when you configure them locally to work against the cloud.

[image: Retrieve TFS Service Credentials]

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code based on impersonation of server

```
var serverUrl  = "";

ICredentials credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
ICredentialsProvider TFSProxyCredentials = new NetworkCredentialsProvider(credentials);

TfsTeamProjectCollection currentCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverUrl), credentials);


// Get the TFS Identity Management Service
IIdentityManagementService identityManagementService = currentCollection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();
// Look up the user that we want to impersonate
TeamFoundationIdentity identity = identityManagementService.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, username, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);


// Open collection impersonated
TfsTeamProjectCollection tfs = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverUrl), credentials, TFSProxyCredentials, identity.Descriptor);

//For example we can access to service WorkItemStore 
var workItemStore = tfs.GetService<WorkItemStore>();
```

Comment: it still prompt an ie windows to ask for my credentials. The first operation doing this is ­­` currentCollection.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();`. is it normal or is it my credentials that doesn't work properly in my code and it should not do any prompt.

Comment: i think that you have problem with your credentials

Comment: this is of course the logical deduction but the same credentials are working fine if I enter them in the prompt

Comment: Check also your domain and your Url

Answer (score 0):

Tfspreview.com now supports basic authentication which would eliminate IE being displayed at all.  See [here](http://tfspreview.com/en-us/learn/code/use-git-and-vs-with-tfs/) for details on how to set this up for your tfspreview.com and then use the username and password you configured.